# Embedded play framework use route file

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

We are trying to start up a play server in embedded mode. It doesn't seem like it can load the route file that is used in stand alone mode. Has anyone run into this before?

Answer (score 0):

Hm.. Not much info to go with.
However, I've run into this sort of issues before, mostly what I did is  `activator clean` 
And then do a `activator run`. This might fix your problem.